# How to copy a selection from one image to another image in GIMP?

Tags: gimp, image-manipulation

Recently I switched from Photoshop to GIMP. I want to copy a selection from one image to another, so that I can fill that selection with color in another image and I can get the shape without recreating it manually. In Photoshop we can copy the layer style, but I can't find that in GIMP. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 31):

It is really as easy as copying the quick mask (the image representation of your selection):

1. Enable quick mask for the image with the selection (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> or Select → Toggle QuickMask)
2. The quick mask appears as a channel called "Quick Mask" in the Channels dialog
3. Select it and copy to clipboard (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>)
4. Enable quick mask for the image that has no selection yet (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>)
5. Select it in the Channels dialog and paste from clipboard (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>)
6. Disable quick mask (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>) to see the selection as dotted lines.

Most other solutions did not really work for me.

Comment: Thank you, this guide is actually usable by somebody who knows nothing about channels in GIMP (me).

Comment: How do I get to the "Channels dialog"? I'm on GIMP 2.10.20.

Comment: It should be noted that this does not produce the selection until _after_ the final step, when you press SHIFT+Q to turn quick masking back off. (I expected it to appear before that step because I assumed that step was ending the tutorial.)

Comment: Also: if you want to move the selection around, move it before the final Shift+Q (i.e. the quick mask), because the selection created from the mask is not movable.

Answer (score 2):

From the first image save the selection into a new channel, copy the content of the channel to the clipboard and then paste it into a fresh channel of the other image. Step by step...

1. Make a new empty channel in the new image.
2. Open the mask channel of the other image where you have saved the selection into a mask channel,
3. Copy the whole thing to the clipboard (Select All then select Copy -> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>).
4. Go back to the (empty) channel of the new image
5. Paste the clipboard data in this channel (Paste -> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd>).
6. Select the image data (RGB) and load the channel data as a selection and whola.

Comment: after saving the selection to new channel how can i paste the selection to new image that is another image?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the alpha channel to restore the selection, just use Alpha to Selection in the pasted layer. You only need to make sure that there is no transparency in the part of the layer that is to be copied:

1. Select what you need
2. Choose a non-transparent layer or create a temporary new one
3. Edit - Copy (Ctrl+C)
4. Go to the image where you want to insert the selection
5. Edit - Paste as - New Layer
6. Layer - Transparency - Alpha to Selection
7. Delete the pasted layer.

Alternative method, using channels:

1. Select what you need
2. Select - Save to channel
3. Ensure the newly created channel is selected and Edit - Copy (Ctrl+C)
4. Go to the image where you want to insert the selection
5. Open “Channels” and create a new channel (a button at the bottom or via the context menu)
6. Ensure the newly created channel is selected and Edit - Paste (Ctrl+V)
7. Open “Layers” and anchor the floating layer (a button at the bottom or via the context menu)
8. Open “Channels” and replace the selection with this channel (a button at the bottom or Channel to Selection in the context menu)
9. You may delete the channels now if you aren't going to reuse this selection anymore, or you may leave them for a later use, just repeat the last action to restore.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you guys complicating it so much:

1. you have one layer, then another on top of it
2. select the top one, be it the boundary, specific colors, w.e, do your selection
3. Now right click on that layer in the layers panel/window and click alpha to selection
4. Now hide the layer to clearly see the one behind it, you'll notice the selection is still active, you can right click on that selection and click invert and delete everything in the new layer to create a cutout of the selection of the first layer, you can paint inside it, you can do w.e with it now. It is "alpha to selection" after right clicking a layer you got a selection from.